# Strange 401 error in nodejs. when calling 2 API it gives auth error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

When I am calling one API from the nodejs it is giving proper reply. But when I am adding one more call it is giving 401 error. I dont know if I have to close some parameter before calling another request.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var request = require('request')
var username = "shruti111";
var password = 'Welcome1';
var planId;
baseUrl = 'https://50d5a18993c046e585b90bc8cc5e1f80-jcs.oci.cloudonline.ml:443';
var baseUrlwoHttps = baseUrl.substring(8);
process.env["NO_PROXY"] = baseUrlwoHttps;
var getUrl = baseUrl + '/IMCMCSREST/rest/v1/PlannedCosts';
var options = {
    url: getUrl,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
}
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        return
    }

    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {
        if (json.items[i].PlanCode == 'Material Cost Planning - PO')
            planId = json.items[i].PlanId;
        //arr.push(json.items[i].PlanId, json.items[i].PlanCode);
    }
    console.log(planId);
})
```

Upto this point it is working properly. If I add below code in the same file it gives 401 error for both call. Otherwise it runs properly.

```
var getUrl = baseUrl + 'IMCMCSREST/rest/v1/PlannedCosts/' + planId + '/ child / CmiCpPlanCostTypesView';
var options = {
    url: getUrl,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
}
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        return
    }

    console.log(body);
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
    var arr = [];
    var x;
    for (i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = json.items[i].CostTypeId;
        //arr.push(json.items[i].PlanId, json.items[i].PlanCode);
    }
    console.log(arr[i]);


})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem here is the `plandId` variable you're using on second request does not have a value. What you can try is calling the second `request` on the callback of first `request`.

Another problem seems to be you are redefining existing variables, though its not fully clear as you didn't show the file as a whole.

Comment: This is the complete file.  Can you tell me how can I use callback here?